# getc with Windows vs Unix

Tags: c

I have a question regarding the following code:

```
while((c = getc(pFile)) != EOF)
{
    if(c != '\n')
    {
         input[index] = (char)c;
         index++;
     } else
     {
         input[index] = '\0';
         index = 0;
     }
}
```

In Windows, this c = getc line reads '\n' (code 10) twice.  For example, I'm reading in the file with the following 2 lines:

```
Hello world
Test
```

c = getc reads in Hello world, but reads in 10 (\n) and 10 once more, resetting the input array to blank (because of the '\0').  In unix, the '\n' only gets read once, so it all works.

Any idea?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: perhaps it is related to how files have their end-of-line signaled ?

Comment: @user834005: how are you opening the file?

Comment: pFile = fopen("input.txt", "a+");

Comment: Are there actually a blank newline after th text in your actual file, as there are in the post here ? (i.e. the post here indicates there are 2 newlines after the text). You should hex dump the file on each platform to verify its content and whether there are one or two \n in it , or perhaps even a \r\n

Comment: Sorry, there is no blank newline, I'm new to stackoverflow and my formatting isn't what it should be.  One enter (or visually it appears to be one enter hah) after each line when viewing on both...  But when I ran that todos tool it did modify the text file and add a second newline so that each had a blank newline under it....   Does that mean the unix file had two newline characters??  Why would it appear ok in nedit?

Comment: Can you do `hexdump -C input.txt` on the linux side, to see the bytes and not just the text?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is the file physically the same, i.e. bit-by-bit, on the two platforms? That's asking for trouble, since the encoding for line ending differs.

Comment: It should be the same file, although I've ftp'ed it from unix to Windows using binary mode (filezilla)...   Is this the issue?

Answer (score 0):

Windows terminate lines with `\r\n`. May be this could help:

```
$ echo test | unix2dos > /tmp/test
$ hexdump -c /tmp/test
0000000   t   e   s   t  \r  \n                                        
0000006
```

Stangely `\r` value is 13, so I dont know wath is going wrong.

Comment: I just ran todos input.txt and the file it modified did have two new lines...  But when I view the unix file in Unix, it definately has 1...

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
while((c = getc(pFile)) != EOF)
{
    if(c != '\n' && index)
    {
         input[index] = (char)c;
         index++;
    } 
    else
    {
         if (!index)
              continue; // dumps repeated '\n'

         input[index] = '\0';
         index = 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: Nope, definately reads in two \n so it does the same thing.  Viewing the file in Unix and Windows looks exactly the same...   I guess Unix puts two \n's ....?

Comment: I added a very dirty, probably not conforming to any standard, hack. Maybe it works for you. I guess I will take a look at the MSDN docs.

Comment: Definately fixes it, thanks.  I think the problem is the file itself though, when I brought it from a unix environment to a windows one.  No need to take a look at MSDN, thanks I appreciate it!

Comment: but that is a very bad hack. I thought of a better solution, check the edit